# Const method overloading

Tags: c++, overloading

I am wandering why C++ chooses to call non const methods on non const object for overloaded methods differing only by const method signature, Namely:

```
#include<iostream>

class Foo
{
 public:
  Foo() {}
  int bar() const { std::cout<<"const version called"<<std::endl; }
  int bar() { std::cout<<"version called"<<std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  Foo f;
  f.bar();
  const Foo g;
  g.bar();
  return 0;
}
```

I understand that for g object, being const, the const version of bar is called. But how about f? The output is

```
version called
const version called
```

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: Do you realise that if the language had specified that the `const` method were to be called even for non-`const` objects, then there would be no way to call the non-`const` method at all? (Which would make defining that method rather pointless.)

Comment: @Marc yes I see the point, still compilers don't make a choice saying "it is pointless". I am interested in hearing a reasoning more like the one given by Anton Saving.

Comment: Your question says you are wondering _why_ C++ chooses to call non const methods, which is about the motivation behind the language specification. If you are interested instead about _how_ the C++ standard arranges so that the proper version indeed gets selected, then you should change the wording of the question to reflect that. Also, I do of course realise that compilers don't directly follow arguments like "it would be pointless", but follow the language rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how overload resolution works.

First, a list of candidate functions is constructed. In your case it consists of two functions:

```
int Foo::bar() const;
int Foo::bar();
```

Each function in the list is converted to accept `this` argument roughly like this:

```
int Foo_bar(const Foo* this);
int Foo_bar(Foo* this);
```

Then the choice is made according to the "Best viable function" (`13.3.3`) part of the C++ standard, which says, in short, that the best function is the one requiring the least number of conversions for its arguments. So if you have `Foo f;` and call `f.bar()`, the best function is the one accepting non-const `this`, because it requires no conversions, whereas the `const` version would require a qualification conversion for `this` from `Foo*` to `const Foo*`.

Answer (score 0):

A non-const object can call both const as well as non-const versions of particular function. Whereas const object can only call const version of that function.

Comment: It does not depend on a compiler. It depends on C++ Standard. All compilers will call the same non-const overloaded function for a non-const object.

Comment: @ravi it's not a matter of efficiency, both versions are equally efficient.

Comment: Also you might want to explain _how_ one can call the const version for a non-const object, since (as the question shows) this is not done by default.